# Plugin: how to get all the types available in my eclipse Workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing an eclipse plugin, and I want to get all the types that are available in my workspace,
like when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,
but in a list or array.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code is referenced from the org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog (which the OpenTypeSelectionDialog triggered by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> inherits from).

If you inspect the fillContentProvider() method you'll see it the org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine, which is passed a TypeSearchRequestor and TypeItemsFilter to match the required types.

If you look at the Javadoc for SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames() and/or debug its execution, you should have a pretty clear idea how to obtain the workspace types into a requestor, and process them accordingly.

Comment: I was searching the same thing;) PluginSpy helps :) +1